# creating class structure in mvvm issues

Tags: c#, wpf, class, oop, mvvm

I have the following Classes:
**Item**

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int? id;
    public int? ID
    {
        get
        { return id; }
        set
        { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                ClearError("Name");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim() == "")
                    SetError("Name", "Required Value");
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private List<MedicineComposition> medicineCompositions;
    public List<MedicineComposition> MedicineCompositions
    {
        set { medicineCompositions = value; }
        get { return medicineCompositions; }
    }
}
```

**MedicineComposition**

```
public class MedicineComposition : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int? id;
    public int? ID
    {
        get
        { return id; }
        set
        { id = value; }
    }

    private Item item;
    public Item Item
    {
        get
        { return item; }
        set
        {
            if (item != value)
            {
                ClearError("Item");
                if (value == null)
                    SetError("Item", "Required Value");
                item = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private Component component;
    public Component Component
    {
        get
        { return component; }
        set
        {
            if (component != value)
            {
                ClearError("Component");
                if (value == null)
                    SetError("Component", "Required Value");
                component = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Component** which has only `id` and `Name`
and the following functions that bring data from database and make the list of my objects:
**GetItems** in `Item` Class

```
public static List<Item> GetAllItems
{
get
{
    List<Item> MyItems = new List<Item>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(BaseDataBase.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_All_Item", con);
    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            Item i = new Item();
            if (!(rd["ID"] is DBNull))
                i.ID = System.Int32.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());
            i.Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
            i.MedicineCompositions = MedicineComposition.GetAllByItem(i);

            MyItems.Add(i);
        }
        rd.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MyItems = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return MyItems;
}
```

**GetAllByItem** in `MedicalCompositions`

```
public static List<MedicineComposition> GetAllByItem(Item i)
{
    List<MedicineComposition> MyMedicineCompositions = new List<MedicineComposition>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(BaseDataBase.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_ByItemID_MedicineComposition", con);
    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter pr = new SqlParameter("@ID", i.ID);
    com.Parameters.Add(pr);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            MedicineComposition m = new MedicineComposition() { };
            if (!(rd["ID"] is DBNull))
                m.ID = Int32.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());
            if (!(rd["ComponentID"] is DBNull))
                m.Component = Component.GetByID(Int32.Parse(rd["ComponentID"].ToString()));
            m.Item = i;
            MyMedicineCompositions.Add(m);
        }
        rd.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MyMedicineCompositions = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return MyMedicineCompositions;
}
```

it's like to use `mvvm` because it let you deal with objects instead of `datatable`, but when i use the previous shape of class structure i have the **following problems:**

- i have at least 1000 records in `Item` Table in database so when i call `GetAllItems` i have slow performance especially when the database in not on local computer.
- i tried to load `Items` when splash screen on, it takes times but take medium performance
- on each update on `Item` table i should recall `GetAllItems` so slow back
  **my questions** is where is the problem that i have in creating **class**, and is this the best way to structure the class in `mvvm`

Comment: if there is alot of data in the db, getting them all will always be slow, that's how it is. the question here is, do you really need all of the data immediately? you can load the data on demand, when you need it. you can load data in chunks, so you won't block the ui, or hit the performance too much. you need to calculate here what you need the most and according to that you program further.

Comment: Updated the answer w/ teh codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you could improve here, for example:

- Given we are talking about `MedicalComposition` it might not be best of ideas to have `nullable` unique identifier
- If you have multiple classes consisting only of `id` and `name` you could use `KeyValuePair<>` or `Tuple<>` instead
- Implement a base class, say `ModelBase` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- Implement `repository pattern` for database related action, cache/page results if possible
- If not yet done, move data- and/or time intensive operations into separate thread(s)
- It's a little confusing that on `Item` you have IEnumerable of `MedicineComposition`s but  also, in `MedicineComposition` you have the `Item`, too? Maybe you don't need it at all or related `Item.Id` would be enough?
- You could add a method to your repository to only return items that have been added/modified/removed since `<timestamp>` and only update what is necessary in your `Items` collection
- You could make some of the properties `Lazy<>`
- Utilize `TAP` (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern)

---

Below is "one go" for your problem w/o blocking the UI thread. It's far from complete but still. `Thread.Sleep`s in repositories are mimicking your database query delays

[image: imgur]

**View\MainWindow.xaml**

Codebehind contains just `InitializeComponents`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="300"
        Width="250">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <!-- Layout root -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Status label -->        
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Background="Bisque"
               Margin="0,3,0,3"
               Content="{Binding Status}" />

        <!-- Controls -->        
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Content="Items" />
            <!-- Items combo -->
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  MaxDropDownHeight="120"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="Auto" 
                  Margin="0,0,0,5"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

            <!-- Medicine components -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.MedicineCompositions}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <!-- Components -->
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <Run Text=" * " />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel\MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _status;
    private Item _selectedItem;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

    public MainViewModel()
        :this(new ItemRepository(), new MedicineCompositionRepository())
    {}

    public MainViewModel(IRepository<Item> itemRepository, IRepository<MedicineComposition> medicineCompositionRepository)
    {
        ItemRepository = itemRepository;
        MedicineCompositionRepository = medicineCompositionRepository;
        Task.Run(() => LoadItemsData());
    }

    public IRepository<Item> ItemRepository { get; set; }

    public IRepository<MedicineComposition> MedicineCompositionRepository { get; set; }

    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Task.Run(() => LoadMedicineCompositionsData(_selectedItem));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private async Task LoadItemsData()
    {
        Status = "Loading items...";

        var result = await ItemRepository.GetAll();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(result);

        Status = "Idle";
    }

    private async Task LoadMedicineCompositionsData(Item item)
    {
        if (item.MedicineCompositions != null)
            return;

        Status = string.Format("Loading compositions for {0}...", item.Name);

        var result = await MedicineCompositionRepository.GetById(item.Id);
        SelectedItem.MedicineCompositions = result;

        Status = "Idle";
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Component : ModelBase
{}

public class MedicineComposition : ModelBase
{
    private IEnumerable<Component> _component;

    public IEnumerable<Component> Components
    {
        get { return _component; }
        set { _component = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class Item : ModelBase
{
    private IEnumerable<MedicineComposition> _medicineCompositions;

    public IEnumerable<MedicineComposition> MedicineCompositions
    {
        get { return _medicineCompositions; }
        set { _medicineCompositions = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetById(int id);
}

public class ItemRepository : IRepository<Item>
{
    private readonly IList<Item> _mockItems; 

    public ItemRepository()
    {
        _mockItems = new List<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            _mockItems.Add(new Item { Id = i, Name = string.Format("Item #{0}", i), MedicineCompositions = null });

    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetAll()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return Task.FromResult((IEnumerable<Item>) _mockItems);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetById(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MedicineCompositionRepository : IRepository<MedicineComposition>
{
    private readonly Random _random;

    public MedicineCompositionRepository()
    {
         _random = new Random();
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<MedicineComposition>> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<MedicineComposition>> GetById(int id)
    {
        // since we are mocking, id is actually ignored
        var compositions = new List<MedicineComposition>();

        int compositionsCount = _random.Next(1, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i <= compositionsCount; i++)
        {
            var components = new List<Component>();

            int componentsCount = _random.Next(1, 3);
            for (int j = 0; j <= componentsCount; j++)
                components.Add(new Component {Id = j, Name = string.Format("Component #1{0}", j)});
            compositions.Add(new MedicineComposition { Id = i, Name = string.Format("MedicalComposition #{0}", i), Components = components });
        }

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return Task.FromResult((IEnumerable<MedicineComposition>) compositions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I dont think your user need to see all the 1000 items at a glance, not even the many thousand of composition and components related.

I situations like this I would:

1. Filter the data. Ask the user for the Item name, category or what else.
2. Delay load. At first load only the (filtered) Items. When the user select an Item switch to an "Item details" View and load the related data (composition and components).

Answer (score 1):

Assign the dataset into the constructor of your `ObservableCollection` property. Else your view will update via a `PropertyChanged` notification for each item that your ObservableCollection performs an Add operation.

Try this:

```
var items = services.LoadItems();
myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<somedatatype>(items);
```

This type of assignment will notify your view once instead of the current way your implementation does which is 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning List, return IEnumerable and yield results as they are needed. Obviously it would only improve performance, when you are not reading all the results, which is actually true in most cases. To do that you would have to remove catch, because you cannot have yield and catch together. The catch could go around con.Open and ExecuteReader and in catch you can yield break:

```
        public static IEnumerable<MedicineComposition> GetAllByItem(Item i)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(BaseDataBase.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_ByItemID_MedicineComposition", con);
        com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter pr = new SqlParameter("@ID", i.ID);
        com.Parameters.Add(pr);
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader rd;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                rd = com.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch { yield break;}
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                MedicineComposition m = new MedicineComposition() { };
                if (!(rd["ID"] is DBNull))
                    m.ID = Int32.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());
                if (!(rd["ComponentID"] is DBNull))
                    m.Component = Component.GetByID(Int32.Parse(rd["ComponentID"].ToString()));
                m.Item = i;
                yield return m;
            }
            rd.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now in case of an exception this is no longer returning null, but can return few items or even empty enumeration. I would rather move the catch to caller of this getter. 
If you need for some reason count of returned items, call GetAllByItem(item).ToArray(). This will enumerate all the items once and gets the length for you. Definitely don't call the enumeration twice to get the length and then enumerate the items:

```
var length = GetAllByItem(item).Count();// this will get all the items from the db
foreach(var i in GetAllByItem(item)) // this will get all the items from the db again
```

Rather do this:

```
var list = GetAllByItem(item); // this will get all the items and now you have the length and the items.
```

Obviously if you need the length for some reason, there is no point in changing to IEnumerable, only for better abstraction.

Other improvement could be, to create the connection only once instead of every time on calling the getter. That is possible only, if you know it won't cause any harm.